# ctrlKey event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to catch the "ctrl + f" event in Javascript.
Even though, any letter on my keyboard fires an event,
"ctrl" does not.
Could you help me, please?

Below, is the code I execute:

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'f') {
event.preventDefault();
document.querySelector("#search").focus(); 
}
```

Comment: I assume you're listening `keypress` event, it isn't fired by all keys on the keyboard (and is also deprecated). Listen `keydown` event instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This was the cause. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'onkeydown' event to capture the ctrl event.

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>ctrlKey example</title>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      function checkKeyPress(e){

        if (event.ctrlKey ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert(
            "CTRL key pressed: " + e.ctrlKey + "\n"
          );
        }
      }

      </script>
    </head>

    <body onkeydown="checkKeyPress(event);">
      <p>Press CTRL</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: aww... i am just going to answer this one but ok, you got this one. And hey upvoted!